# Is it normal practice storing each request in the object in angular?

Tags: angular, caching

I have a code for storing/caching each(or almost each) request in the object, but not sure is it good practice or not.

```
store = [];
fetchAll(params: any, cache = true): Observable<PostsInt[]> {
 let posts = this.http.get<PostsInt[]>(this.getApiUrl('/posts'), {
   params
 });

 if (cache) {
   const key =
     Object.values(params).join('') + APP_CONFIG.data.defaultLocale;
   if (!this.store[key]) {
     posts = posts.pipe(
       publishReplay(1),
       refCount()
     );
     this.store[key] = posts;
   }
   return this.store[key];
 }
 return posts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to. It depends on the loading balance and the things you want to do with those informations afterwards. There is already an similiar [Stackoverflow Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51300434/5677688) which answers it. For example: Simple CRUD-Applications dont need to store any informations, thats why they are CRUD-Applications. Another fresh post from April 2019, [Store and Redux](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-redux-ngrx-rxjs/) depends on what framework you are using exactly.