# NgRX state management with Angular application

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

Whether should we apply ngRx to state management in angular app?
I see some companies used it, but some else is not.
For me, I have more than 2 years exp develop angular application but I don't see any case need to use state management.
Only RXJS to resolve all problems I met.
Any one who can compare and explain about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's an often discussed problem. In short, while it can solve issues if you DON'T know if you need NgRX then you most likely don't need it. Here is a nice answer that has compiled some questions and answers you have about the topic. No need to repeat ourselves.
[Do I need NgRx?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51300434/9349240)