# How should a project using ngrx handle non-shared state

Tags: angular, ngrx

Not really sure this is an appropriately objective question for SO, but would welcome views.

When searching for examples and best practice for ngrx, I find authors understandably focus on its value in sharing state between components.

However many of the components we write often read/write from APIs, but that data is of no interest outside of the component. However there seems to be an implicit expectation that if you are using ngrx elsewhere in your project then you will retrieve this data by raising an action, handling in an effect and persisting in a store.

Although this approach reduces component code (admittedly just shifting complexity/code into the effects layer) and contributes a consistent approach to the project, it requires a lot of code and abstraction that doesn't seem to bring any material benefits.  I also find that the model representing your application state becomes bloated and difficult to navigate.

So my question is, when using ngrx do you just accept the above disadvantages and use it consistently throughout, or are you a bit more discerning and only utilise it for use cases where state is being shared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is tough to answer, because there is no correct answer I believe. I would basically consider this:

- are you limited by internal rules for the project?
- do you consider best practices to be untouchable thing?
- can you design an architecture which would allow to easily mix two approaches?

If your answers are **no**, **no** and **yes** (in this order), then I would just implement the CRUD in a "standard service approach". I just did that on a project I overtook and it saved us hundreds of lines of codes and speed up creation of pages from days to hours.

In such case, NgRx might be nice to use for filtering and paging, as it would allow to create reusable components, store their states and simply retrieve them where needed.. But using it for CRUD stuff is pointless.

I'm a big fan of NgRx but at the same time I hate to use it in simple CRUD projects. Personally, I see no advantage of it. I don't need data to be persisted, if I don't see them. And even if I wanted to, re-hydrate functionality is simple to implement even without NgRx.

Years ago I wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67313634/3359635) to a similar topic and I still work in the same manner.

Comment: Thanks for contributing and it seems we are on the same page.  It's interesting that you have also interpreted best practice to be use ngrx even for stateless CRUD, and you acknowledge that not using it saves a lot of time and code.  I need to get myself to an ngrx conference and ask the question "what is the advantage of using it where state is not shared, other than consistency"